Why is the ViewModelProvider class private
I wanted to get started with developing android apps. I created a new project in Intellij. It can't build because Intellij says that the class ViewModelProvider has a private constructor.

I tried a few things like the class ViewModelProviders but this class is deprecated and not working for me. stackoverflow posts and android docs tell me to write new ViewModelProvider(this).get(...) but I can't, since it's private. How can I fix this issue?
This are my dependencies
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.mndl.testapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.mndl.testapp"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.2")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
}

Thanks in advance
